# Problem with recaptcha3 for .NET MVC website

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, recaptcha

I'm quite new in web development, have only couple of weeks of experience.
Currently working on C# website and can't get ReCaptchaV3 to work.

I have a subscribe form that shows up as a modal when user clicks on a "subscribe" button on the bulletin page.

In the form I have hidden input field: `<input type="hidden" name="Google-captcha-token" id="GoogleCaptchaToken">`
It generates the token when "Sign Up" button of the form is clicked.

My problem is - how to I get a hold of that value on the backend in C#? and then send it to google for verification? I also need to check if value I got from Google is within needed range and everything is good continue submitting the form.
This is where I stuck. I understand that I need to catch that value and work with it in the controller, but don't know how to do that.
Hope someone can help me out on this one.

This is how the code in the controller looks

```
 public class BulletinController : _SharedController {       
    public ActionResult Index(int p = 0) {          
         var perPage = 10;
        if (p < 1) {
            p = 1;
        }
        var starting = (p * perPage) - perPage;
        if (starting < 0) {
            starting = 0;
        }
        var token = HttpContext.Request.Form["Google-captcha-token"];
        var ns = new NewsServices();
        var newsArticles = ns.GetNewsArticles(starting, perPage);
        var count = ns.GetNewsArticlesCount();
        ViewBag.Paging = Pagination.Generate(count, starting, perPage);
        return View(newsArticles);
    }                             
    public ActionResult Details(int id) {
        var article = new NewsServices().GetNewsArticleByID(id);

        if (article == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(article);
    }                     
}
```

I watched a lot of videos on how it should be done, but none of them worked.

It seems to be a problem that view of the page is already using a model and that model is autogenerated. So looks like I can't use another model. Current model is also a list model (not sure what that exactly means though).

The other thing is that submission of the form is not going through the back-end and done through the **constantcontact** JavaScript sign up script.

Hope somebody will be able to help. Thanks.